# when save record and use new value not change in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I edit posts and use new value but not changes .

```
post.approved = 'unapproved'
post.is_new = false
post.save
if post.approved == 'approved'
   puts 'Approved'
end
```

**why if posts approved and change it to unapproved enter to puts 'approved'.**

Post.rb

```
class PostModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum is_approved: { unapproved: 'unapproved',
                      approved: 'approved',
                      approved_rejected: 'approved_rejected',
                      unapproved_rejected: 'unapproved_rejected'}
end
```

Comment: How does your model look like?

Comment: @spickermann please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change enum value:

```rb
post.approved!
post.approved?  #-> true
```

Check this out: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Your enum column name is `is_approved` so you should use that for saving the value in it.

```
post.is_approved = 'unapproved' # you can also save by using post.unapproved!
post.is_new = false
post.save
if post.is_approved == 'approved' # you can also check using post.approved?
   puts 'Approved'
end
```